# How to access the paritcular column in csv file using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

While I'm trying to compare the two csv and then access the particular column of both
I can't access it .

Need the remedy to access the particular column of csv file while looping.

Comment: Show [mre]. Check [ask]

Answer (score 1):

If you are using pandas, then after you create a dataframe, use df['your column name'] to access that particular column. Please note that the name you provide as 'your column name' should exactly match that in your csv file.

Eg:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('path to your file')
column = df['your column name']
```